# How well do Catholics in the USA know Latin?

Tags: catholicism, language, latin

Latin is the official language of the Catholic Church. And, after Croatia got independent in the early 1990s, the Catholic Church has lobbied the Croatian government to introduce Latin as an obligatory subject in most Croatian high-schools for two years (grade 9 and grade 10). So, in Croatia, young Catholics (and around 80% of Croatians are Catholics) tend to know some Latin.

I was wondering, how well do Catholics in other countries speak Latin? How is it in the USA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How well do Catholics in the USA know Latin?**

*How well do Catholics in the USA and other countries speak Latin?*

Generally speaking, Catholics have a very poor working knowledge of Latin, while many would have the ability to pronounce Latin well enough to recite Latin prayers at mass or say the rosary. The ability to to true speak Latin would probably be less than one percent (1%).

Keep in mind that although Latin is the official language of the Church, studying Latin is not an obligation, but is highly encouraged. Very many Catholic high schools do not even teach Latin in their curriculum, which I personally find appalling. With the Mass being allowed in the vernacular, very few lay Catholics see a need to understand Latin at all.

The ability to read, understand and pronounce Latin does not always translate to having the ability to speak Latin fluently, especially in a conversation. I can read read, understand and pronounce Latin, but I cannot carry on a conversation in Latin! ***Non possum!***

> Nationally, a 2017 survey found that just 2 percent of grade school students taking foreign language courses were studying Latin. Comparatively, 67 percent were enrolled in Spanish.
>
> Spoken Latin is as much the subject of controversy as it is a success story. Pedicone lumps naysayers into two camps: those who argue that intensive Latin programs aren’t intensive enough, as most don’t require students to speak the language exclusively, and those who will always insist on the grammar-translation method as the pinnacle of Latin pedagogy. - [Spoken Latin Is Making a Comeback](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/why-spoken-latin-is-making-a-comeback-180981621/)

Many Catholic websites offer a list of [Latin prayers](https://www.traditionalcatholic.co/latin-prayers-2/) which they encourage lay Catholics to know by heart.

Many priests today will not be able to speak in Latin and would have to admit that they could not do so. If asked, I wonder how many could reply ***non possum!*** (I cannot!).

Comment: Are we talking about classical Latin? "Latin is now considered a dead language, meaning it's still used in specific contexts, but does not have any native speakers. When did Italy stop speaking Latin? - The early 16th century saw the dialect used by Dante in his work replace Latin as the language of culture."

Comment: https://www.polilingua.com/blog/post/italian-similarities-to-latin.htm#:~:text=Latin%20is%20now%20considered%20a,as%20the%20language%20of%20culture.

Comment: @Lesley By definition the Church employs Ecclesiastical Latin and not classical Latin. Generally speaking they are the same except the most prominent difference is in the way Latin is pronounced. Other differences do exist also.